# How do I unselect a completed quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

A completed quest in my journal is selected, as shown below:

[image: screenshot]

This causes new quests to not be selected immediately.

How can I unselect it? Clicking on the quest title does not deselect it.

Comment: Usually clicking on the quest title (next to the diamond) would toggle the diamond (indicating a quest is tracked). Does that not work in this case?

Comment: @TimS. Thank you for pointing that out - it does not work. I edited the question accordingly, I simply forgot to include that.

Comment: It's been a little while since I played Skyrim... what does "Ziele" mean in English? "Quest"? I can tell the darker grey usually means that part of the quest has been completed, and the lighter grey (like the text towards the top) is used for objectives not yet complete. Did you try saving/reloading the game? If that still doesn't work, I'd guess it's bugged out.

Comment: @TimS. "Ziele" are the little steps you take, e.g. find item X, talk to Y, etc...; Yes, the dark grey means it's completed and a non-completed quest would be lighter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This glitch kinda occurs when you're on the quest when it's activated the entire time and then when it completes and you didn't activate another quest, it will still be marked as activated. Try to reload a previous save before you completed Brelyas's quest, activate another uncompleted quest, and complete the quest you said to have the bug on.

Comment: Unfortunately I completed that quest like two months ago, but I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: @RAnders00  2 in game months or 2 real life months?

Comment: real life months.